# How to initialise CComSafeArray which a SAFEARRAY returned from a Scripting.Dictionary Keys method

Tags: c++, safearray, scripting.dictionary

I'm using a Scripting.Dictionary from the COM Library "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" (c:\windows\System32\scrrun.dll).  I'm using import to get my wrappers and these are working.  After adding some items, I'm trying to get the list of keys but I am stuck.

I have got some way.  I can get the `SAFEARRAY` of keys out of the Dictionary but I want to use the `CComSafeArray` class defined in `<atlsafe.h>` but I cannot figure out a good construction.  Currently, the constructor throws an `ATL` assertion complaining about `vartype` mismatch.  Admittedly, the newly constructed CComSafeArray has a `vartype` of 52428 of CCCC in hex and this looks potentially like uninitialised memory.  But the type inferred doesn't look right either, I am expecting the vartype of the safearray to be strings but the assertion code gives vartype 12 which is UI2.  Very strange.

Anyway, this is probably easy for someone familiar with this.  Here is a console program Minimal, Complete, Verifiable, Example (MCVE) as per SO standards.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlsafe.h>

#import "c:\windows\System32\scrrun.dll" raw_interfaces_only,raw_native_types, named_guids, rename("DeleteFile", "_DeleteFile"), rename("MoveFile","_MoveFile"), rename("CopyFile", "_CopyFile"), rename("GetFreeSpace", "_GetFreeSpace")

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    CoInitialize(0);

    CComQIPtr<Scripting::IDictionary> dictColours;
    hr = dictColours.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(Scripting::Dictionary));
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) { return hr; }

    CComVariant varZero(0); //dummy value, only interested in keys

    hr = dictColours->Add(&variant_t(L"red"), &varZero);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) { return hr; }

    hr = dictColours->Add(&variant_t(L"green"), &varZero);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) { return hr; }

    hr = dictColours->Add(&variant_t(L"blue"), &varZero);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) { return hr; }

    long lColourCount(0);
    hr = dictColours->get_Count(&lColourCount);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) { return hr; }

    CComVariant varColoursKeys;
    hr = dictColours->Keys(&varColoursKeys);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) { return hr; }

    SAFEARRAY keys(*(varColoursKeys.parray));

    //fine up to this point

    CComSafeArray<VARIANT> varColours;

    /* The following code throws an error for the next (line) live, vt=52428 or hex CCCC which looks like uninitialised memory
       whilst GetType() returns 12 which is UI2 (and somehow I expected string type 8!) 
    VARTYPE vt;
    HRESULT hRes = ::ATL::AtlSafeArrayGetActualVartype(const_cast<LPSAFEARRAY>(psaSrc), &vt);
    ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(hRes);
    ATLENSURE_THROW(vt == GetType(), E_INVALIDARG);
    */

    varColours = (keys);

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
SAFEARRAY keys(*(varColoursKeys.parray));
```

To this:

```
SAFEARRAY* keys = varColoursKeys.parray;
```

(optionally, first make sure that `varColoursKeys.vt` has the `VT_ARRAY` flag)

And then you can query `keys` for its `vt`:

```
hr = ::ATL::AtlSafeArrayGetActualVartype(keys, &vt);
```

Note that `varColours = keys` is going to make a *copy* of the array data.  If that is not what you really want, then you should `Detach()` the array from the `CComVariant` (or just use `VARIANT` directly and not `CComVariant`) and `Attach()` it to the `CComSafeArray` (then you can use the `CComSafeArray::GetType()` method).

Also, you need to make sure all of your COM wrappers go out of scope and release resources *before* you call `CoUninitialize()`.

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlsafe.h>

#import "c:\windows\System32\scrrun.dll" raw_interfaces_only,raw_native_types, named_guids, rename("DeleteFile", "_DeleteFile"), rename("MoveFile","_MoveFile"), rename("CopyFile", "_CopyFile"), rename("GetFreeSpace", "_GetFreeSpace")

HRESULT DoIt()
{
    CComQIPtr<Scripting::IDictionary> dictColours;
    hr = dictColours.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(Scripting::Dictionary));
    if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

    CComVariant varZero(0); //dummy value, only interested in keys

    hr = dictColours->Add(&variant_t(L"red"), &varZero);
    if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

    hr = dictColours->Add(&variant_t(L"green"), &varZero);
    if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

    hr = dictColours->Add(&variant_t(L"blue"), &varZero);
    if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

    long lColourCount(0);
    hr = dictColours->get_Count(&lColourCount);
    if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

    VARIANT varColoursKeys;
    hr = dictColours->Keys(&varColoursKeys);
    if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

    CComSafeArray<VARIANT> varColours;
    varColours.Attach(varColoursKeys.parray);

    // use varColours as needed...

    VARTYPE vt = varColours.GetType();

    LONG lLower = varColours.GetLowerBound();
    LONG lUpper = varColours.GetUpperBound();
    for (LONG i = lLower; i <= lUpper; ++i)
    {
        VARIANT &v = varColours.GetAt(i);
        // use v.bstrVal as needed ...
    }

    //...

    return S_OK;
}

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(0);
    if (FAILED(hr)) { return hr; }

    hr = DoIt();

    CoUninitialize();
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: Great , that works. Thanks very much. I do not need `varColours = keys` now (I sometimes experiment with the `= operator` when a constructors are not working).  Code now responds to methods in the `CComSafeArray` class, `.GetAt` for example, which is fabulous.  Thanks again.

Comment: Re `CoUninitialize()`, yeah, this code was an excised from a bigger program, the Com wrappers will have definitely gone out of scope by the time main is exited.